# Query Second page of 10000 elasticsearchresttemplate

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data

This is my code below

```
   private ElasticsearchRestTemplate template;       

int elasticSearchMaxSize = 10000;
    
            SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                    .withPageable(PageRequest.of(1, elasticSearchMaxSize/*, Sort.Direction.ASC, "meta.time_created"*/))
                    .build();
            Page<myData> page = this.template.queryForPage(searchQuery, myData.class);
```

I am unable to query the 2nd page of elasticsearch with a max of 10,000.

The error is

```
Result window is too large, from + size must be less than or equal to: [10000] but was [20000]
```

I am query 2nd page with 10,000 records at once. How can i do this?

Comment: Change max result window by setting index.max_result_window = 50000; in elasticsearch.yml file in etc/elasticsearch

Comment: my documents are growing, may be more than 1 million. I need to be able to query 2nd page and so on

Comment: Your result window was too larger than expected, and this should sort it. To address your growing documents, you can have pagination logic implemented.

Comment: Yes i want to do pagination. If i change PageRequest.of(13, elasticSearchMaxSize/*, Sort.Direction.ASC, "meta.time_created"*/), it doesnt get me the 13th page

Comment: Use `Scroll API`. It's helpful when user wants deep pagination. .Read more in docs : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-scroll

Answer (score 0):

Go to Dev Tools in Kibana and run below query :

```
PUT your_index_name/_settings
 { 
  "max_result_window" : 500000 
 }
```

It should give you :

```
{
  "acknowledged": true
}
```

Run your code, It should work now!

Comment: What if i have 10 million documents? and i want to query 2nd page of 500,000. it will throw the max result windows error?

Comment: By default the offset + limit is limited to 10,000. This can be modified at a cluster level, but isn't recommended.

When paginating in this manner, Elasticsearch has to parse the query, build the search context, distribute the query to applicable shards, gather the results, skip past $offset items, then read out $limit items and destroy the search context for each page which means that the deeper we paginate, each page is more expensive than the page before it.

The 10,000 limit is there for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

- **For big data, This can be done in conjunction with searchScroll.**
- **Pass the Query with the same condition and use searchScroll to build the paging return value; Use commons search to query the
  required data result collection.**

*my spring-boot with ServiceLog code*

```java
@Service
public class ServiceLogRepresentationService {

    final ElasticsearchRestTemplate elasticsearchRestTemplate;

    public ServiceLogRepresentationService( ElasticsearchRestTemplate elasticsearchRestTemplate ) {
        this.elasticsearchRestTemplate = elasticsearchRestTemplate;
    }

    // pageable = PageRequest.of( page - 1, size )
    public PagedRepresentations< ServiceLogRepresentation > getServiceLogs( Pageable pageable ) {

        BoolQueryBuilder aggregateQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery( );
        // ... when the code to add some conditions to the aggregateQueryBuilder is written here

        NativeSearchQueryBuilder searchQueryBuilder = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder( );
        NativeSearchQueryBuilder pagingSearchQueryBuilder = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder( );

        if ( aggregateQueryBuilder.hasClauses( ) ) {
            searchQueryBuilder.withQuery( aggregateQueryBuilder );
            pagingSearchQueryBuilder.withQuery( aggregateQueryBuilder );
        }

        // paging needs
        SearchScrollHits< ServiceLog > pagingSearchScrollHits = this.elasticsearchRestTemplate.searchScrollStart(
                1,
                pagingSearchQueryBuilder.withMaxResults( 1 ).build( ),
                ServiceLog.class,
                IndexCoordinates.of( ServiceLog.class.getAnnotation( Document.class ).indexName( ) ) );
        SearchPage< ServiceLog > searchPage = SearchHitSupport.searchPageFor( pagingSearchScrollHits, pageable );

        // Actual search results
        SearchHits< ServiceLog > searchHits = this.elasticsearchRestTemplate.search( searchQueryBuilder
                        .withPageable( pageable ).build( ),
                ServiceLog.class );
        Collection< ServiceLogRepresentation > logs = searchHits.getSearchHits( ).stream( ).map( SearchHit::getContent )
                .map( ServiceLog::representation ).collect( Collectors.toList( ) );

        // PagedRepresentations.of( int page, int pages, long total, Collection< T > representations );
        return PagedRepresentations.of( searchPage.getNumber( ) + 1, searchPage.getTotalPages( ),
                pagingSearchScrollHits.getTotalHits( ), logs );
    }

}
```